# Get action from unbutton behind UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift

I've got a custom `UITableViewCell` with this structure:

A back view, which contains 2 `UIButton` and one `UIScrollView` in front which contains labels.

I permit to drag the scroll view on the left, so that I show the buttons behind.

But I found a problem: in this way I can't press unbuttons, because on dragging I update the content offset and so they remain behind.

I know that I can manage `UIScrollView`'s origins instead of Content Offset, but I don't really like this solution.

Is there a way to intercept `UIButton` pressure even if it's behind `UIScrollView`?

P.s.: the project in which I'm working is in swift, even if I can develop, or translate, the code from objective C!

Comment: try `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like by dragging the scroll view, you mean scrolling - which just changes the content offset.  Without moving the scrollview frame or changing the UIButton's z order, you won't get touch messages directly from the UI.

Given those constraints, the only alternative I can suggest is a UITapGestureRecognizer on the parent view (you call it the back view.. maybe the cell's contentView).

Upon getting the tap, you can hit test the UIButtons and invoke their actions if the hit test succeeds.

A better alternative is probably to reorganize your views.  If you just want to put the buttons under a sliding door, don't use a scroll view.  Use just a plain old view and move it's frame when user pans.

Comment: I've already considered this solution, however I thought that there would be another solution whit UIScrollView instead of Panning UIViews. Thank you!!